# No schema for Azure ClearDb MySql Database

Tags: mysql, azure, cleardb

I have created a managed MySql database in Azure which uses ClearDb as a database provider. I appear to have a database if I go to Azure and click through to the ClearDb dashboard. However when I connect in MySql Workbench using the username and password provided by Azure then I log in ok but I cannot see any schemas. When I type  SHOW GRANTS I get the following:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 4
```

Is there a database and if so how do I get access to it? If there isn't one how do I create one because I don't have the permissions to do so. I assume there is a database because the ClearDb dashboard seems to indicate there is.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this by creating a Titan database. My original database was a Mercury one which is the smallest free one. I still imagined I could do something with it, but obviously not....